# How to make Passwd::Keyring::Auto persistent on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, mercurial-keyring

I'm using Passwd::Keyring::Auto for Perl on Windows. I noticed that the keyring is not persistent. 
Can I force it to be persistent on Windows?

http://search.cpan.org/~mekk/Passwd-Keyring-Auto-0.2703/lib/Passwd/Keyring/Auto.pm

Ex.

```
use Passwd::Keyring::Auto;  

my $keyring = get_keyring(app=>"Test", group=>"Windows");
my $username = "someuser";
my $password = $keyring->set_password($username, $password, "mylostspace.com");
```

When my program ends, I'd like to get whatever passwords I had in the keyring like below:

```
$password = $keyring->get_password($username, "sometest.com");
```

However, the $keyring->is_persistent() always returns 0. I tried forcing the option PERSISTENT => 1 when I create the keyring, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I simply haven't developed windows backend yet, as I do not own windows machine at the moment. Writing module like Passwd::Keyring::WindowsVault (or similar) should not be hard (especially considering one can consult python keyring library source for inspiration), but requires some programmer with Windows development environment. In case you are (or anybody else is) interested in writing one, I would be glad to help, but I am simply unable to test such a module or even to prepare binary distribution for CPAN.

Once such module exists, integrating it into Passwd::Keyring::Auto would be trivial

Pointers:

(what should Passwd::Keyring backend implement)
https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Passwd-Keyring-Auto/lib/Passwd/Keyring/Auto/KeyringAPI.pm

(APIs used by pythonic library)
https://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib/src/8aadf61db38c70a5fe76fbe013df25fa62c03a8d/keyring/backends/Windows.py?at=default
(in perl it should be replaced with some XS as I do not know about anything like ctypes, module code structure would likely be similar to that of https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/perl-keyring-gnome/src )

Answer (score 1):

And one more note: with some effort it should be possible to use Passwd::Keyring::PwSafe3 backend on Windows, to keep passwords persistent. You will still need to provide opening password for this storage (no open thanks to OS authorization) on every run but in case you have multiple passwords or want to manage them from GUI too it may make sense. You can try setting environment variable PASSWD_KEYRING_AUTO_PREFER to PwSafe3 to use this keyring (of course install the module beforehand).